# Need to choose files manually instead of directing the vb code to a folderpath

Tags: excel, vba

I did a vb code which is reading multiple text files from a folder and then parsing specific data from it. In the code I have hard coded a folderpath strPath = "C:\Users\smim\Desktop\Mim\Excel\". Now I would like to be able to choose the folder and files manually instead of hard coding the folder path. Here is my code :

```
Sub Parse()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
Dim WriteToRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strCurrentTxtFile As String
Dim count As Variant, yellow As Variant, red As Variant, 
Dim YellowC As Variant,RedC As Variant, filecounter As Variant
Dim strPath As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 count = 0
 red = 0
 yellow = 0

YellowC = 0
RedC = 0
 strPath = "C:\Users\smim\Desktop\Mim\Excel\"

'Set Book3 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

MsgBox ("Started")
'~~> Start from Row 1
'WriteToRow = 1
Cells(3, 1) = "Error"
Cells(3, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(3, 2) = "Warnings"
Cells(3, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Cells(1, 3) = "Error"
Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(2, 3) = "Warnings"
Cells(2, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

 strCurrentTxtFile = Dir(strPath & "test_*.txt")
' MsgBox (strCurrentTxtFile)
'~~> Looping through all text files in a folder

Do While strCurrentTxtFile <> ""

    Dim list() As String
    '~~> Open the file in 1 go to read it into an array
    Open strPath & strCurrentTxtFile For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1

    strData() = Split(MyData, vbLf)
    LineCount = UBound(strData)
  '  MsgBox (LineCount)

    'Assigning length of the list array
    ReDim Preserve list(LineCount + 1)

    For x = 0 To (LineCount - 1)
        'For x = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
       'Parsing each line to get the result only ( after = sign)
       s = Split(strData(x), "=")
       b = UBound(s)

       'MsgBox (s(1))
       'Assigning Values to the list array
      list(x) = s(1)

     Next

        'MsgBox ("This is list" & list(2))

     'Active Cell 2
    Range("A2").Activate

    'Get row number
    dblRowNo = ActiveCell.Row

    'Get col number
    dblColNo = ActiveCell.Column
    'MsgBox (dblColNo)


  '  ReDim Preserve list(LineCount)

    For i = 0 To (LineCount - 1)
           Cells(3, 3 + i + 1).Value = i
        'Looping and assigning Values to the Cell
        'For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        tempParsing = Split(list(i), ":")

       ' MsgBox (tempParsing(0))
         If tempParsing(0) > 0 And tempParsing(0) < 10 Then
           Cells(dblRowNo + count + 2, dblColNo + i + 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
           yellow = yellow + 1

           ElseIf tempParsing(0) >= 10 Then
            Cells(dblRowNo + count + 2, dblColNo + i + 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
             red = red + 1
           ElseIf tempParsing(0) = 0 Then
             Cells(dblRowNo + count + 2, dblColNo + i + 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If

   'Looping and assigning Values to the Cell
      '  For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
      Cells(dblRowNo + count + 2, dblColNo + 1) = yellow
    Cells(dblRowNo + count + 2, dblColNo) = red
    Cells(dblRowNo + count + 2, dblColNo + i + 3).Value = list(i)







      Next
      Cells(3 + count + 1, 3).Value = count
      count = count + 1
      yellow = 0
       red = 0
     strCurrentTxtFile = Dir



    Loop
     For t = 4 To 175

    If Cells(t, 1).Value > 0 Then

       Cells(t, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If

 If Cells(t, 2).Value > 0 Then


    Cells(t, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

  End If
       Next



  'Cells(9, 1) = "linecount = "
       'Cells(9, 2) = LineCount

 MsgBox "Done"

 For f = 4 To 175

     If Cells(f, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

           YellowC = YellowC + 1

        ElseIf Cells(f, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

           RedC = RedC + 1

     End If
  Next

  For g = 4 To 175

   If Cells(g, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

       YellowC = YellowC + 1

   ElseIf Cells(g, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

       RedC = RedC + 1

    End If
  Next

 For u = 0 To (LineCount - 1)

  Cells(dblRowNo, dblColNo + u + 3) = YellowC
   Cells(1, dblColNo + u + 3) = RedC

  Next


  YellowC = 0
  RedC = 0


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to incorporate Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) to your code.  That opens an Explorer window and allows a file to be selected.

Comment: You can use the `Application.GetOpenFilename Method ` with `multi-select= true`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I have tried  strPath=Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True) but its giving me error every time